# Unable to build Angular project using Jenkins

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, gruntjs, jenkins-plugins, bower

I need to run the following commands:

```
bower update 
grunt build
```

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build\workspace>export PHANTOMJS_BIN=/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs 
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build\workspace>export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$WORKSPACE/.config" 
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build\workspace>bower update 
'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build\workspace>grunt build 
'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. This is what I am doing now.

```
set PATH=PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;
              C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
              C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;
              C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
              C:\Ruby200\bin;
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;
              C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;
              C:\Users\appcito\AppData\Roaming\npm
cd testnew
cd ui
call npm cache clear
call npm install
call bower cache clear
call bower install
call grunt build
```

Answer (score 4):

`export` command is not for Windows; it's for *nix machines. If you want to set some path on Windows OS, use `set` command. Remember that this value will be set only for the *current shell*. Once you close the command prompt, the value will also get unset.

For example,

```
set PHANTOMJS_BIN=/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs
set XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$WORKSPACE/.config"
```

For the third and fourth error, you have to make sure that `bower` (and `grunt`) command is in the PATH otherwise the system will never be able to locate the command as is happening right now. To make it work, just add the *path* to bower executable in `PATH` variable.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;path_to_bower_executable
```

For example, if bower command is in c:\bower\bin, just add

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\bower\bin
```

To set your changes permanently, you can go through the steps mentioned in [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) link.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build\workspace\ui>set PATH=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\bower\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\grunt 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build\workspace\ui>bower update 
'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build\workspace\ui>grunt build 
'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Path seems to be correct. However, you are removing other values from the PATH variable although it should not affect the output you're getting. You should be _appending_ the path for `bower` and `grunt` to the existing PATH variable instead of _removing_ all the old paths that were set in PATH variable. So, use this: `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\bower\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\grunt`. Now coming to the issue, can you please paste the output (echo %PATH%) that you get after running the above command?

Comment: By the way, if you're using `Master-Slave` configuration, you can also add the variable and its value as key-value pairs in your Node's configuration page under `Node Properties` section. If it's a standalone system, you can configure the same in Jenkins' configure page under `Global properties` section.

Comment: I am now doing.cd ui
set PHANTOMJS_BIN=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\phantomjs
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\bower\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\grunt\lib
set XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$WORKSPACE/.config"
bower update
grunt build --verbose
tar -h -C . -czf ./ui-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz dist.But bower is not working and grund build never ends